# How to write a complete Python wrapper around a C Struct using Cython?

Tags: python, c, wrapper, cython

I am writing a a high level interface for a C library for Python using Cython.
I have an extension Type `A` that initializes the library with a pointer to a more complex C context structure `c_context`. The pointer is saved in `A`.
`A` also has a `def` function which in turn creates another extension Type `B` initializing another C structure with a library function call. This structure is needed for the subsequent library calls made in `B`.
`B` needs the `c_context` pointer from `A` which is wrapped by me within the extension type `py_context` in order to pass it to `__cinit__` from `B`:

```
#lib.pxd (C library definitions)
cdef extern from "lib.h":
    ctypedef struct c_context:
        pass

#file py_context.pxd
from lib cimport c_context

cdef class py_context:
    cdef c_context *context
    cdef create(cls, c_context *context)
    cdef c_context* get(self)

#file py_context.pyx
def class py_context:
    @staticmethod
    cdef create(cls, c_context *c):   
        cls = py_nfc_context()  
        cls.context = c  
        return cls

    cdef c_context* get(self):
        return self.context
```

Passing the wrapper with the correct C context works perfectly.

Now I need to get the C struct out of `py_context` again and save it in `B`. I added `cdef c_context get(self)` to `py_context.pxd/pyx`.
Calling `py_context.get()` from Bs `__cinit__` results in: `AttributeError: py_context object has no attribute get.`

It seems like I do not get my head around when to call `cdef` functions in Cython.

**So my question is:** What is the best way to extract the C struct from my wrapper class again?

Comment: Have you read this? http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/clibraries.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trouble is that Cython doesn't know the data type of your `py_context` variable at compile time. Calls to `cdef` functions are resolved at compile time and there exists no mechanism to figure it out at runtime by attribute lookup (as with normal Python functions).

[Note that `def` functions written within Cython are still compiled and can specify data types, so are perfectly capable of calling `cdef` functions if they have the right information.]

You don't give the relevant code where it's going wrong (the constructor of type `B`), but here's an very simplified example which will hopefully give you a couple of ways to fix it:

```
cdef class A:
    cdef f(self):
        return

def f1(var):
    var.f()

#f1(A()) # will fail at runtime with an attribute error
```

In `f1` the type of `var` is unknown, and thus you can't call `cdef` functions.

```
def f2(A var):
    var.f()

f2(A()) # will work
f2(1) # will fail, int can't be converted to A
```

In `f2` the type of `var` is constrained to be `A`, and therefore it can happily call `cdef` functions associated with `A`. If you pass something that isn't `A` to it you'll get a `TypeError` at runtime.

```
def f3(var):
    cdef A another_reference_to_var = var # this does test that the types match
    another_reference_to_var.f()

f3(A()) # will work
f3(1) # will fail, int can't be converted to A
```

The function `f3` can take a variable of any type. However, when you assign it to `another_reference_to_var` which is `cdef`ed to be an `A` it checks that the type matches (and raises a runtime exception if it doesn't). Since `another_reference_to_var` is known to be `A` at compile time, you can call `A`s `cdef` functions.

Essentially, you need to specify the type of the relevant input to your `__cinit__` function.

Comment: +1 This is a better answer so I promptly removed mine since it was a bit misleading. [Here](https://github.com/cythonbook/examples/tree/master/07-wrapping-c/02-wrapping-c-structs-mt-random) is a url with a full example of wrapping a struct for OP to see if he needs.

Comment: Works like a charm. The missing type information in Bs `__cinit__` was the problem. Adding `py_context` resolves the problem.
Your information should be added to the Cython docs since they are a bit vague at times.